# Analyzing Music in Java

Tags: java

Greetings!

I was wondering if it's possible to make music-based games in Java? I've played games like Beat Hazzard and Audiosurf and stuff like that and I was considering making one like that - that dynamically loads songs the user selects and finds pieces of information (like bass notes) and does something in return.

I don't even know where to start, but I have found ways to play music (through certain classes others provide or the Java Sound API). Anybody ever done anything like this before? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it is. I think the term you should be Googling for is [Java Signal Processing and analysis](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+signal+analysis#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&q=java+signal+analysis+and+processing&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229).

There is a related [SO post on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636686/signal-processing-library-in-java) as well as numerous other Java libraries and source examples (see the Google search results from above.) Here is a [page with applets that perform a variety of signal analysis](http://www.dsptutor.freeuk.com/). Might not be exactly what you need but should be a start. And [MARF](http://marf.sourceforge.net/), from the SO post mentioned above, looks VERY promising!

Comment: Most of these projects seem to be dead in the water though :( Oh well, still useful information, thank you :)