# How to compare 2 voice in Android

Tags: java, android

I need some way to compare 2 voices if they match or not but can't use Google service because I need it to work in offline mode. Thank so much for watch or help.

Comment: Can you share source code because i didnt get any example for this. How you solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it so hard to use google or the internal search?

Have a look at this...

[Compare voice wav in android or voice tag ( voice commands ) API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935691/compare-voice-wav-in-android-or-voice-tag-voice-commands-api)

Comment: If this is the answer tag it please or comment if not :O

Comment: Can you explain about "How to convert WAV files to the frequency domain for use FFT libraries" .Thank you