# Java Voice Biometric Application

Tags: java, macos, voice

First I want to say that I'm german so sorry if my english is incorrect at some point.
I want to write a java program for mac (My first "real" program so far) which can read in a keyword or something you say and recognize your voice kind of like a code. I want that program to open right after the mac turns on or in lock screen so you can only enter if you verify. So my problem is, I have no idea how to compare the voices. I have read the questions to that topic but that is not really what I want. Also I have no Idea how to let it pop up right when the mac turns on but that is another problem I'll deal with later :D

Hope you understand my question and thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare voices you can start from [How to compare 2 voice in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062031/how-to-compare-2-voice-in-android) or from [iSpeech](https://www.ispeech.org/developers/java). Another point from you can start is [rivr](http://rivr.nuecho.com/).

Comment: Thanks, thats a really nice solution but i was wondering if there isn't any way I can program it myself and don't use other programs like rivr...