# How to convert WAV files to the frequency domain for use FFT libraries

Tags: java, android

[Compare voice wav in android or voice tag ( voice commands ) API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935691/compare-voice-wav-in-android-or-voice-tag-voice-commands-api) in answer number 2 I don't know how to convert the time-domain data of the original WAV file into frequency-domain data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's an api which may helps you to achieve your goal http://code.google.com/p/musicg/