# Inertial navigation signal processing on Java

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I'm interested in processing measurements from gyroscopes and accelerometers in a Web application. It would be nice to have tools for integrating Euler angles, and other such geometry. Linear algebra such as least-mean-squares (or some better approach) to merge GPS and IMU data is also an important feature. The application does not involve any real-time feedback or robotics.

Also, spectral analysis will be useful. Finding principal frequencies, analyzing the profile as pitch shifts up and down. (Tonal pitch, not the angle. This is not navigation-related.) Is it likely to find a tool that will do that with accelerometer data in three dimensions?

The target platform is server-side Java. There's a lot out there for Java, but so much seems education oriented. I'm pretty new to both DSP and Java… it seems that this might be an unusual request, but not outlandish. The most important thing is to have a solid foundation with Fourier analysis and matrix operations. Not a gaming library or Mindstorms toolkit — that seems to rule out a lot. But I know people do science and serious math in Java, too.

Are there existing Java libraries that combined can provide such functionality?

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636686/signal-processing-library-in-java, particularly http://www.dickbaldwin.com/tocdsp.htm and http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.2/index.html?org/apache/commons/math/transform/package-tree.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some links:

http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/

http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

And more  here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#Java

Comment: +1, Thanks! But these are quite generic libraries, just matrix operations and some integration. I don't think FFT is too much to ask for. I'm holding out for Kalman filters and Euler angle integration…