# compare two audio file in java

Tags: java, fft, frequency, jmf, pitch

i want to make a project in which i am going to record a user's voice and then compare it with a stored voice. I searched for that and i come up with MFCC and FTT algorithm. but i really don't understand that how they work.Only theory i found on internet not any practical knowledge. I don't have an electrical background so not so much knowledge about waves and signal.

I found that there are some features of voice like 
-pitch
-amplitude
-frequency
-energy

is there any way to calculate all these through coding. My project is in java.If anyone has some information regarding this so please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/636686/178280 might be of some help to you.

Comment: I am also finding material to start a similar project, as well as practical code. I suggest you read this pdf. See if it can help. http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1003/1003.4083.pdf