# How can I calculate integrals of step functions in the most simple way?

Tags: java, math, statistics, time-series, mean

I have a time series of recoreded frequencies, from which I would like to calculate secondly means. However the sample rate is not constant, which means that a simple arithmetic mean is wrong. What I would actually like to compute is the integral of the step function (described by the timeseries) within each secondly interval.

Consider for example this time series:

```
08:11:23.400 -> 49.9 Hz
08:11:24.200 -> 50.1 Hz
08:11:24.600 -> 50.15 Hz
08:11:24.800 -> 50.05 Hz
08:11:25.100 -> 49.95 Hz
```

The arithmetic mean of the second `08:11:24.000 - 08:11:25.000` would be (50.1 + 50.15 + 50.05)/3 = 50.1. But this is not the mean fequency measured in that second. It is instead:
(200*49.9 + 400*50.1 + 200*50.15 + 200*50.05)/1000 = 50.06, because the measured frequencies were true for different amounts of time.

This is the calculation of a weighted mean (with the hold times as weights) or equivalently the calculation of the integral of the step function (and then deviding by the time).

First of all: **Is there a name for this specific calculation?** It seems a rather standard computation on time series to me. Not knowing a name for this makes it hard to google for it.

Second: **Which java library supports such a calculation?** I would like to avoid implementing this by myself. I refuse to believe that there is no good standard java library offering this. I was looking into the apache commons math library but without any luck (but again: maybe I'm just missing the correct term to look for).

Comment: I'm confused---are you saying you don't want to implement a weighted average yourself? That's all this is. It's just a few lines of code. Or do you mean you want something that takes the time series, parameters for the interval, and returns the weighted average? While I have slightly more sympathy for that, it's still not a lot of work. Why do you want to avoid doing it yourself?

Comment: Well, why reinvent the wheel if it already exists? The chances that there are any kind of bugs in my wheel are relatively high, whereas a standard library will be well tested in most cases. Second, there's more standard statistics I'd like to do, which would probably be scoped by the appropriate library as well and which would allow uniform handling of different statistics.

Comment: @benjamin did you ever find a useful answer to your questions? I'm working through the same 10 years later.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure the formula 200*49.9 + 400*50.1 + ... is correct. It implies that the frequency 49.9 is in effect from 08:11:23.400 to 08:11:24.200, as if the frequency sensor meters future frequency. I would rather think that it meters mean past frequency. Then, is the frequency really a step function? Or is a saw-tooth function closer to reality? Or even a smooth function, reconstructed with splines?

As a result, I would recommend to compute the integral by yourself, and be ready to change the calculation formula. As for bugs, you equally can make errors while choosing function from a library, and when setting its parameters.

Comment: Yes, I think that the frequency 49.9 is in effect from 08:11:23.400 to 08:11:24.200 (note that the values I gave above are made up as example). The frequency meter pushes an update every time the frequency changes (up to some hysteresis, i.e. ignoring changes below some thershold). That's why it looks as if it would be measuring into the future. About the bugs: actually there are not that many bugs to implement for such easy stuff, but I find it more a good principle to use established libraries where they exist and are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many libraries in Java which can do this properly. But the basic thing you are looking for is digital signal processing.

Here's a similar question: [Signal processing library in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636686/signal-processing-library-in-java)

Comment: Although a DSP library - if it existed - would probably include my needs, i don't think that that's exactly what I am looking for since I'm not interested in FFT, low pass filtering etc. I was thinking of some statistics package. Do you know a common name for the step function integral I described?